# How to wordwrap in GTK#?

Tags: .net-core, gtk#

## Question

I want to show some text on a window in GTK#. The length of text is not predetermined and wordwrap is needed.

## A sample test to be displayed

"woo----- --------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------!"

## Expected result

[image]

## Code

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.Init();

    Window window = new Window("helloworld");
    window.Decorated = false;   //Remove title bar.
    window.SizeAllocate(new Gdk.Rectangle(new Gdk.Point(0, 0), new Gdk.Size(100, 100)));
    var Black = new Gdk.RGBA
    {
        Alpha = 1,
        Red = 0,
        Green = 0,
        Blue = 0
    };
    var White = new Gdk.RGBA
    {
        Alpha = 1,
        Red = 1,
        Green = 1,
        Blue = 1
    };
    window.OverrideBackgroundColor(StateFlags.Normal, Black);
    window.Show();

    Label label1 = new Label("woo----- --------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------!");
    label1.OverrideColor(StateFlags.Normal, White);
    label1.OverrideColor(StateFlags.Focused, White);
    label1.OverrideColor(StateFlags.Active, White);
    label1.MaxWidthChars = 20;
    label1.Show();
    window.Add(label1);

    Application.Run();
}
```

## Result

[image]

It automatically resizes the window with no wordwrap.

## Another shot

```cs
window.Resizable = false;
```

If I add this code...

## Another result

[image]

It still resizes the window. I cannot understand the function of Resizable property if it does not work.

How can I get the expected result?

## Environment

- Dotnet core 3.1 Windows/Linux
- GtkSharp 3.24.24.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Wrap property.

```cs
label1.Wrap = true;
```